# How to remember the choice of the run type in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala

Each time I try to run my Scala program in Eclipse it asks me whether it is Scala or Java. I select Scala, it runs, then I try to run it again, and Eclipse again asks me... this is tiresome.

How to make my choice stick, so I would be asked once or even not at all (extension should be recognized, I think)?

### Update

See Luigi answer -- I am **NOT** asking about key assignment. I am asking about remembering my choice of the type of the file when running it. So it has nothing to do with editing the keyboard (actually I don't use any keyboard shortcut to run app).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run a Scala project as a Scala application by default in Eclipse IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872438/how-can-i-run-a-scala-project-as-a-scala-application-by-default-in-eclipse-ide)

Comment: @LuigiPlinge, thanks, but no. I am talking about remembering my choice, not about defining key maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Launching Preference Page's "Launch Operation" setting and make sure you change it from the default to always launch the previously launched applicattion (or choose it from the Run/Debug button's drop-down menu).
[image: Launching Preference Page]
[image: drop-down]

Comment: Thank you, I am not accepting it (yet), because it has other side effect -- when I change the app/file, and hit select to run it, it will run the previous one. And since I am switching back and forth among test and main app, the result is I am stuck with manual choosing as previously.

Comment: That's when you use the drop-down list from the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of the Scala IDE are based on JDT - the Java Development Tools. This means that eclipse is sometimes unable to distinguish between a Scala and a Java application.

Some time ago this problem was discussed on the [mailing lists](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-ide-dev/Vdmgmd1h3Zo/a3u-Fyj0JBoJ). See the discussion there for some suggestions on how to avoid the upcoming frame.

Comment: Seems like yet another reason to drop Eclipse and use IntelliJ -- thank you. I will keep your answer unmarked for a day, maybe somebody will come up with an idea, if not, I will accept it.